# Question about definition of inverse function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse-function

So, I've been reading Precalculus books and I found a question in the definition of inverse function,
some of my books say:

> Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a real function, where $X,Y\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that: $g\colon Y\to X$ is the inverse function of $f$ if for each $x\in X$, such that $$g(f(x))=x,\ \forall x\in X\quad\text{and}\quad f(g(y))=y,\ \forall y\in Y.$$

And others of my books say:

> Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a real function, such that $g\colon Y\to X$ is the inverse functdion of $f$ if for each element $x\in X$, if always it’s true that
> $$y=f(x)\quad\text{if and only if}\quad x=g(y),\qquad \forall x\in X\text{ and }\forall y\in Y.$$

So, my question is:
What of these is the true definition of inverse function? and
If posible to proof the other definition with the real definition of inverse function?
Further,  What if the proof the link a bijective function and inverse function?

Comment: Please do **not** use math mode for italics. If you want to do italic text, use markup: `*italic text*` renders everything between the `*` in itlic.

Comment: Those statements don’t parse. If you want to ask us about the definitions given in your books, then kindly copy them **exactly**. I’ll wager dollars to donuts that your books do not say what you wrote, because what you wrote are not proper mathematical statements as written (though it is fairly easy to guess what they probably *do* say, it is not what you wrote)

Comment: Short answer: both. Both are the proper definition. They are each logically equivalent to each other, and different educators/authors will start with one and derive the other. If an educator gets finicky about which one you should use, then it should be made very clear which definition they consider to be "the" definition.

Comment: @Albert Luna Palamino: Or if you wish a practical away from definitions ..take a transparent plastic sheet, graph the two curves, align axes,  flip the sheet out of plane around symmetry line $x=y$.. to find no change between $(f,g).$

Answer (score 1):

**Claim.** Let $X,Y$ be sets amd $f\colon X\to Y$, $g\colon Y\to X$ be functions. Then the following are equivalent

$$\tag1\forall x\in X\colon g(f(x))=x\;\land\;\forall y\in Y\colon f(g(y))=y$$
$$\tag2 \forall x\in X,\forall y\in Y\colon y=f(x)\leftrightarrow x=g(y)$$

*Proof.*
Assume $(1)$. To show $(2)$, let $x\in X, y\in Y$ be given. We wan to show $y=f(x)\iff x=g(y)$. So first assume $y=f(x)$. Then by the first part of $(1)$, $g(y)=g(f(x))=x$. In summary, $y=f(x)\to x=g(y)$. Conversely assume $x=g(y)$. Ten by the seoncd part of $(1)$, $f(x)=f(g(y))=y$. In summary, $x=g(y)\to y=f(x)$. IN overall summary, $y=f(x)\leftrightarrow x=g(y)$. As $x, y$ were arbitrary elements of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, we have shown $(2)$ from $(1)$.

Next, Assume $(2)$. To show the first part of $(1)$, let $x\in X$ be given. As $f$ is a function $X\to Y$, we can let $y=f(x)\in Y$. Specialize $(2)$ to $x$ and $y$ to find $y=f(x)\leftrightarrow x=g(y)$. By choice of $y$, the left side holds, hence $x=g(y)=g(f(x))$, or: $g(f(x))=x$. As $x$ was an arbitrary element of $X$, this shows $\forall x\in X\colon g(f(x))=x$.
To show the first part of $(1)$, let $y\in Y$ be given. As $g$ is a function $Y\to X$, we can let $x=f(y)\in X$. Specialize $(2)$ to $x$ and $y$ to find $y=f(x)\leftrightarrow x=g(y)$. By choice of $x$, the right side holds, hence $y=f(x)=f(g(y))$, or: $f(g(y))=y$. As $y$ was an arbitrary element of $Y$, this shows $\forall y\in Y\colon f(g(y))=y$.
Now that we have shown both $\forall x\in X\colon g(f(x))=x$ and $\forall y\in Y\colon f(g(y))=y$, we have in fact shown $\forall x\in X\colon g(f(x))=x\;\land\;\forall y\in Y\colon f(g(y))=y$, i.e., we have shown $(1)$ from $(2)$.

In summary, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

Consider a map ${ f : X \to Y }.$

**Def**: Inverse of ${ f }$ is a map ${ g : Y \to X }$ such that ${ (f \text{ sends } x \text{ to } y) }$ ${ \iff (g \text{ sends } y \text{ to } x) }.$

Here the constraint "${ (f(x)=y) \implies (g(y) = x) }$" is equivalent to "${ g \circ f = \text{id} _X }$".
The constraint "${ (f(x)=y) \impliedby (g(y) = x) }$" is equivalent to "${ f \circ g = \text{id} _Y }$".

So equivalently:
Inverse of ${ f }$ is a map ${ g : Y \to X }$ such that ${ g \circ f = \text{id} _X }$ and ${ f \circ g = \text{id} _Y }.$